# Can't OPEN Eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04 - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library

Tags: eclipse, swt, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 newly. Also i installed Java 7. I  try to install eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz. i extracted this file in /home/ramprabhu location. Then i try to run eclipse executable file. I got error as see the log file.

**My log file:**

```
 !SESSION 2012-06-10 22:47:35.959 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_04
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-06-10 22:47:36.757
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /home/ramprabhu/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/247/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-3740.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    no swt-pi-gtk in java.library.path
    /home/ramprabhu/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk-3740.so: /home/ramprabhu/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk-3740.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
    Can't load library: /home/ramprabhu/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk.so

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

I am not able to run eclipse. How to solve this problem and run eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing 64-bit and 32-bit. Download the 64-bit version of Eclipse and use the 64-bit version of Java 7.

Comment: how do i understand if eclipse is 32 bit or java is 32 bit? I was using synaptic to install jdk7 from the webupd8 ppa and to install eclipse.

Comment: running `java -version` will show you 32-bit or 64-bit mode. A quick way to find if Eclipse is 32 or 64-bit is to do `find . -name 'org.eclipse.swt*.jar'` and see if it returns x86_64 for swt

Comment: executing `java -version` says: 
`java version "1.6.0_26" - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-383-11M3720) - Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02-383, mixed mode)` So, is this 32bit or 64bit?

Answer (score 55):

Try with the following command

- 64 Bits System: `ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/`
- 32 Bits System: `ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/`

Comment: Had the same problem and for my 32 bit system just a copy paste of the above command saved me! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

worked it out by copying the `libswt` files to `~/.swt/lib/linux/x86(or x86_64)`

for 32 bit:

```
/bin/cp /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/
```

for 64 bit:

```
/bin/cp /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
```

Answer (score 6):

I came across this error when tried to start 32-bit build of Eclipse under 64-bit linux. The problem was solved after installing **ia32-libs** package.

Answer (score 4):

I faced with this problem after installing QNX Momentic IDE (it based on 32-bit eclipse distribution) for Blackberry 10 development. I haven't chance to install ia32-libs because

> $ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>   However the following packages replace it:
>     lib32asound2 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
>
> E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate

I found solution in [this post](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/01/linux-setup-blackberry-10-development/)

> sudo aptitude install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libc6:i386 libcairo2:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 zlib1g:i386

I'm sure this solution will help with simple 32-bit eclipse also

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Also check the error log to see any other dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how i solved the issue 
`aptitude search libswt-gtk`

Then `sudo  apt-get install` the ones not installed
[image]

Comment: You are a life saver! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem with with my 64bit system, the ln is solution worked, magic, 
64 Bits System: ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/