# Ubuntu: SWT App Can't Load GTK Library

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jar, swt

I have supplied the Linux SWT jar and packaged my app in Eclipse to include swt.jar inside my app's jar. When I try to run it on Ubuntu, I get the following error text (posting only cause):

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
>
> no swt-pi-gtk-4234 in java.library.path
>
> no swt-pi-gtk in java.library.path
>
> /home/nifty/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk-4234.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Can't load library: /home/nifty/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk.so

This indicates to me it can't load a GTK file, but anything beyond that, and I'm at a loss. I'm only using Ubuntu to test my app, so I know very little.

Comment: Can you include the manifest file here?

Comment: Edited question to include error and found out this error is with the GTK library, so I reworked the question.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Can't open Eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04 - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970754/cant-open-eclipse-in-ubuntu-12-04-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-could-not-l) Also I found an entry in the [Ubuntu bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/swt-gtk/+bug/975560). Maybe you can find useful workarounds or solutions there.

Comment: I'm sure this would have helped if I didn't screw up poor Ubuntu to the point of re-installation. But, since I re-installed under VMWare, my SWT app now works properly.

Comment: I solved by following this https://askubuntu.com/a/1194489/1155600

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I fix that missing lib on my Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /home/ywu/.eclipse/473605238/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/361/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4236.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```
ywu@ywu-HP-8100:~$ aptitude search libgtk2.0-0
    i   libgtk2.0-0                   - GTK+ graphical user interface library                                                         
    p   libgtk2.0-0:i386              - GTK+ graphical user interface library
ywu@ywu-HP-8100:~$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Answer (score 7):

On my 64-bit Debian Wheezy/testing I solved it by doing

```
apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk
```

(http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/262868/).  If your system isn't a 64-bit system then this suggestion is not applicable.

Comment: This should not be closed. THe only detail that should be added to the question is that the environment is a 64 bit one, and eclipse needs ia32 libs

Comment: how to do the same in linux? this command is not working in linux 64 bit.

Comment: found for 64 bit system, it helped me.
### sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 (run 32 bit lib for 64 bit system)

### sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libxtst6:i386

Comment: Installing `libswt-gtk-3-java` fixed the issue in Debian sid.

Comment: `ia32-libs-gtk` has been removed from Debian on 2013-11-03. The last version which had it was `squeeze`. Today the problem can be fixed by installing `libswt-gtk-4-java` or `libswt-gtk-3-java`.

Answer (score 4):

With latest Ubuntu (18.10), installing `libswt-gtk-3-java` fixed it.
To do so, from a terminal, type the command:
`sudo apt install libswt-gtk-3-java`

For most updated version, I would suggest following link: 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=swt-gtk

Answer (score 0):

For more recent releases, if it says it can't find `libgtk-3.so.0`, the obvious package you need to `apt-get install` is [libgtk-3-0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libgtk-3-0). However, it seems on Ubuntu Zesty (17.04) there isn't such a package, so I needed to switch to Xenial (16.04). Artful and later should work too.

Also, the [graphical Eclipse Installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/?show_instructions=TRUE) won't work without this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on i386/debian with docker:

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```