# Eclipse won't start after new Java

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I have installed java on my linux machine (Ubuntu 12.04). (I don't know much about linux by the way). I tried to start Eclipse (Indigo), I have this error message:

"An error has occurred. See the log file    /home/mrx/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/1386462523174.log."

I went to the log file to find this:

```
!SESSION 2013-12-07 19:14:38.354 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-12-07 19:14:48.790
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
    no swt-gtk in java.library.path
    Can't load library: /home/mrx/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-gtk-3740.so
    Can't load library: /home/mrx/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-gtk.so

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at     org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Before installing Java, I had openjdk, and I still have it, I haven't removed it, and eclipse would work fine with that, then.

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Try updating Eclipse (downloading it from the Eclipse website)

Comment: You aren't telling us (1) how you're running eclipse, (2) what you may have thought of, tried, or debunked.  The message says it cannot find SWT, so the initial thought should be that it is not on the classpath.  Do you know what the classpath is in the environment in which you are running eclipse?  If it worked before, has something changed about that classpath?  Does it maybe have something in it that was put there by an installation procedure you ran recently?  There are too many things that could cause this for someone to tell you, with this much info, which one it is.

Comment: By "new Java" do you mean you changed Java versions? Which Indigo download is it? Is it 32 or 64-bit? Is the new Java 32-bit or 64-bit? What about the GTK version? Why still Indigo when this is the latest Java version?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970754/cant-open-eclipse-in-ubuntu-12-04-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-could-not-l

Comment: This has solved the issue: ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/