# running qde(eclipse for blackberry developpement)

Tags: eclipse, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, momentics

i've installed  the Momentics IDE 2.0 for blackberry but something's wrong. i'm using debian x64, and when i try to run it, i get an error that says:

```
MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
     /home/User/bbndk/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/361/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4236.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    no swt-pi-gtk in java.library.path
    /home/User/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk-4236.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Can't load library: /home/User/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk.so
```

so on the blackberry page it says to install (ia32-libs) kind of librairies. i'm not able to install them because i get a message saying that:

```
some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Some of the answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970754/cant-open-eclipse-in-ubuntu-12-04-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-could-not-l) question cover this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got there coz in my case I was blocked from running java due to the ia32-libs.
In short, this is how I installed momentics-2.0 on my ubuntu 13.10 x86_64.

1. Add this line to the bottom of your /etc/apt/sources.list (Not sure if still need this yet): 
   deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main universe
2. Installed these libs as a replacement of ia32-libs:
   ywu@ywu-HP-8100:/install$ sudo apt-get install  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
3. Fix the missing libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0:
   ywu@ywu-HP-8100:/install$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
4. Fix the missing libXtst.so.6:
   ywu@ywu-HP-8100:/install$ sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
5. Install momentics-2.0:
   ywu@ywu-HP-8100:/install$ sudo ./momentics-2.0-201310251201-linux.gtk.x86.bin

Good luck!